# Minimum 1-D finite pavement to fit in varying-length K bricks

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Suppose you have a set of $k$ bricks, each of varying sizes. we want to fit all these brings one by one on a straight pavement of length $N$. we know the sizes of each brick but we do not know

a) the order in which they are placed, and

b) the positions on the $N$-length pavement in which they will be placed. What is the minimum length of $N$ such that we can play any of the $k$ bricks in any order and in any position?

Comment: Unless you give precisions about the values of the sides, no answer is possible.